# Simplifying tests on a random set

Tags: functions, conditional, expression-test

I would like to simplify:

```
Tableinit = {{"a", "b"}};
c = {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}};
Do[Print[set = {RandomReal[{0, 3}], RandomReal[{0, 3}]}]; 
 testP = {a -> set[[1]], b -> set[[2]]};
 If[And @@ 
   Thread[(a > c[[1, 1]] /. testP) && (b > c[[1, 2]] /. 
       testP) && (a > c[[2, 1]] /. testP) && (b > c[[2, 2]] /. 
       testP) && (a > c[[3, 1]] /. testP) && (b > c[[3, 2]] /. 
       testP)], Print["yaha"]], {3}]
```

So that I get for example:

```
{0.0135703,0.225061}
{1.34055,2.56798}
{2.74278,2.92141}
yaha
```

Into something more like this with an implied loop:

```
Tableinit = {{"a", "b"}};
c = {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}};
Do[Print[set = {RandomReal[{0, 2}], RandomReal[{0, 2}]}]; 
 testP = {a -> set[[1]], b -> set[[2]]};
 If[And @@ Thread[(a > c[[1]] /. testP) && (b > c[[2]] /. testP)], 
  Print["yaha"]], {3}]
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `a > c[[1]]` you need something like `Thread[a > c[[All, 1]]]` or `Thread[{a, b} > c[[1]]]`, e.g.

```
c = {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}};

Do[Print[set = {RandomReal[{0, 3}], RandomReal[{0, 3}]}];
 testP = {a -> set[[1]], b -> set[[2]]};
 If[And @@ Flatten[Thread /@ {a > c[[All, 1]], b > c[[All, 2]]} /. testP],
  Print["yaha"]], {3}]
```

or

```
Do[Print[set = {RandomReal[{0, 3}], RandomReal[{0, 3}]}];
 testP = {a -> set[[1]], b -> set[[2]]};
 If[And @@ Flatten[Thread[{a, b} > # /. testP] & /@ c],
  Print["yaha"]], {3}]
```

Comparison including two Mr.Wizard-style variations.

```
c = {{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}};

Do[
 Print[set = {RandomReal[{0, 5}], RandomReal[{0, 4}]}];
 testP = {a -> set[[1]], b -> set[[2]]};

 If[(a > c[[1, 1]] /. testP) && (b > c[[1, 2]] /. testP) &&
   (a > c[[2, 1]] /. testP) && (b > c[[2, 2]] /. testP) &&
   (a > c[[3, 1]] /. testP) && (b > c[[3, 2]] /. testP),
  Print["yaha"]];

 If[And @@ Flatten[Thread /@ {a > c[[All, 1]], b > c[[All, 2]]} /. testP],
  Print["yaha"]];

 If[And @@ Flatten[Thread[{a, b} > # /. testP] & /@ c],
  Print["yaha"]];

 If[And @@ Thread[{a, b} > Max /@ Transpose@c /. testP],
  Print["yaha"]];

 If[AllTrue[c, And @@ Thread[# < {a, b}] &] /. testP,
  Print["yaha"]],
 {8}]
```

> ```
> {4.74172,3.22551}
> yaha
> yaha
> yaha
> yaha
> yaha
> {4.00698,1.34669}
> {3.91794,0.437822}
> {1.33563,2.52507}
> {4.56379,3.27889}
> yaha
> yaha
> yaha
> yaha
> yaha
> {2.30426,3.34091}
> {0.417722,0.19335}
> {1.05824,1.34333}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to preserve some semblance of your operations but I realize that just makes things confusing for this simple case.  If you update your question to something where this doesn't work I'll try to address that too.

```
c = {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}};

Do[
 Print[set = RandomReal[{0, 3}, 2]];
 If[Max[c] < Min[set], Print["yaha"]],
 {3}
]
```

Attempting to make this more general I suggest you look at [`AllTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html), e.g.

```
AllTrue[c, # < Min[set] &, 2]
```

Or a bit more efficiently if `set` is longer:

```
AllTrue[c, # < m &, 2] /. m -> Min[set]
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't set up the best example because indeed it could be solved here with min and max, which is not the case in my operations but Thanks!

Comment: @user52518 Did you attempt to apply `AllTrue` to your problem?  I suspect it is applicable as you seem to want to test all elements of `c`.